# Focus mode side effects

Tags: alternate-reality, brain, health

**Premise :**

The brain is expensive to maintain, 20% of your food expenses go to your brain so it doesn't rot and die of hunger, just to maintain an idle brain. Focusing on something burns way more calories and is incredibly fatiguing; the average human can maintain a state of focus for only 20 minutes at a time, trained white collar workers with years of experiences can focus for a maximum of [4 hours a day](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/wellness/productivity-focus-work-tips/2021/05/31/07453934-bfd0-11eb-b26e-53663e6be6ff_story.html), after which every further decision is affected by [decision fatigue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_fatigue) on top of general tiredness and every task that requires problem solving becomes harder and harder. Chess masters who after decades can focus on their game for 12 hours a day burn up to 6'000 kilocalorie in a single session, which is enough to make the average non overweight person lose so much weight that they become anorexic in a few weeks.

> The 1984 World Chess Championship was called off after five months and 48 games because defending champion Anatoly Karpov had lost 22 pounds. "He looked like death," grandmaster and commentator Maurice Ashley recalls.

The cost of the brain itself should be self explanatory for why we feel fatigued and frustrated when we have to focus and think for long periods, an animal that doesn't feel pain from focus would just waste all their energy focusing on any random event and die of hunger.

**Problem**

I want for focus mode(1) to be a thing in my world, whether it is something that only few species or specific individuals can do through biological innate means or maybe it's a drug that makes one focus.

(1) Define "focus mode" : being able to focus on something for as long as focus mode is active without feeling any restrictions such as fatigue or pain.

theoretically one could induce many diseases on themselves if the focus mode was left on for too long, and after turning it off, the individual should feel all the pain and effects of overuse.

I want focus mode to be a skill, a passive skill that can be turned off and on in my project and I need to know the cost of resources for this skill like health points/energy and punishments for using focus mode too much, this I will figure it out myself based on your answer.

**Question**

What are the effects of indefinite focus and being numb to brain pain and fatigue, thus focusing at maximum effort for too long(2)?

(2) Define "Too long" : above the personal threshold of the individual, if the person can focus 20 minutes at best, then too long equals to a range between 21 and infinite.

**What qualifies as a good answer?**

a list of the most important long term(3) side effects and permanent ones on the brain and also rest of the body if there are any.

(3) Define "long term" : anything that takes more than 3 days to recover from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go with increased brain metabolism.

Muscle cells can burn pretty much any kind of fuel directly (fat, carbohydrate, lactate, etc). Power output is highest with carbohydrates, but still pretty decent with fat. Muscle cells also store glycogen and fat locally.

However, neurons aren't good at using fat, they use mostly glucose and lactate. They don't have much storage either, so they must be supplied by the blood.

So hypoglycemia will turn off your brain, but not your heart or muscles.

Let's suppose our guy has increased brain metabolism, neurons working faster, consuming lots of glucose and lactate. He will produce more heat and sweat a little, but the brain won't overheat due to being cooled by blood flow. This glucose mostly comes from the liver's glycogen stores, which only contain up to 400 kcal. More will be available if our guy had a carbohydrate-rich meal just before, and the liver can also metabolize fat into glucose, but only at a certain throughput of course.

If this focus mode is an abnormally high brain metabolism, while the guy has an otherwise normal body, using focus mode for too long would deplete the liver's glycogen storage and exceed its ability to replenish it, leading to hypoglycemia. If it is mild, then our guy will have to reduce brain metabolism to whatever fuel is available, which means after 8 hours of super smart focus mode, he'll have to be an idiot or take a nap for a few hours, unless he consumes glucose rich food. Even then, glycogen stores take a while to fill up.

Another option would be to exercise a bit, to make the muscles release lactate that will then be used by the brain. This means focus mode would work better while exercising (this is pretty noticeable).

To support this increased metabolism, he would also have to train like an athlete so the rest of the supporting hardware, especially the heart, can do its job properly.

Anyway. How does it feel to burn about 5000 calories in a day... just ride a bicycle and you'll know ;)

When the muscles run out of glycogen and have to run on fat, it's impossible to not notice it. Basically your power output drops by a huge chunk, almost 50%, and sprinting is definitely not available. Since it's local storage, the muscles that didn't do any work are unaffected and don't feel tired.

Otherwise everything works fine and it's possible to keep running on fat until you fall asleep, it's just much slower and the "sprint margin" disappears because the reserves are exhausted. If you're working below the available metabolic "power supply", it's fine, but anything above that becomes increasingly difficult to do and to recover from.

Then once at home you're super sluggish until the next day as the reserves fill up again.

If this guy's brain behaves in a similar way, it could be entertaining.

Answer (score 2):

**Lost in focus.**

[image: leaf]

[source](https://www.bostonglobe.com/2021/09/22/opinion/mathematician-sees-reassuring-logic-lifes-twists-turns/)

Focus will slowly acquire a life of its own.  Focus is rewarded by things that absorb focus.  There are things the world with a great capacity to absorb focus, and as the focus gains momentum it becomes more and more clear that every object in the world has an infinite capacity to absorb focus.  It will be more and more difficult for the individual who is sustaining focus to resist focusing on these things.  Some people become lost, and cannot come back into the world without help.

Some of these people who do come back into the world leave it again to lose themselves in focus.  It can be hard to return from Nirvana.